# Aligning multiline Java strings in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, string, formatting

I'm a little new with the Eclipse formatter system. Given an assignment to `String` over a couple of lines like this:

```
String cypher = "OPTIONAL MATCH (update:UPDATE {name: {name}}),"
        + "(update)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(installation)<-[:CURRENT]-(computer:COMPUTER {name: {computerName}})"
        + "RETURN update, installation, computer";
```

I wish to have Eclipse format it when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and produce the following, with all `+` signs aligning nicely under `=`:

```
String cypher = "OPTIONAL MATCH (update:UPDATE {name: {name}}),"
              + "(update)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(installation)<-[:CURRENT]-(computer:COMPUTER {name: {computerName}})"
              + "RETURN update, installation, computer";
```

How can I achieve that?

I'm using this formatter.xml file which I've imported into Eclipse: http://pastebin.com/iThW8Lub Maybe some tweak here is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with the formatter settings in Eclipse, and was not able to achieve *exactly* what you are looking for. I suspect that it is not possible with the given formatter settings (you could, however, find or write a plug-in that will do what you want).

That being said, I was able to achieve two options that are the closest to what you are looking for.

This is for Eclipse Kepler:

Go to `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`. Click to `Edit` your profile. Go to the `Line Wrapping` tab. Select `Expressions`. For `Line wrapping policy` select `Do not wrap`. Now expand the `Expressions` list and select `Binary Expressions`.

Now choose the wrapping policy you prefer. This will affect the number of elements on each line before the wrapping. I go with `Wrap when necessary`, but you could choose to have every element on a separate line.

For indentation policy, choose `Indent on column`.

Now, you can choose to check/uncheck `Wrap before operator`, which will give you Effect 1 and Effect 2 respectively:

## Effect 1: [x] Wrap before operator

```
String cypher = "OPTIONAL MATCH (update:UPDATE {name: {name}}),"
                + "(update)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(installation)<-[:CURRENT]-(computer:COMPUTER {name: {computerName}})"
                + "RETURN update, installation, computer";
```

## Effect 2: [ ] Wrap before operator

```
String cypher = "OPTIONAL MATCH (update:UPDATE {name: {name}})," +
                "(update)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(installation)<-[:CURRENT]-(computer:COMPUTER {name: {computerName}})" +
                "RETURN update, installation, computer";
```

In my opinion, Effect 1, while less neat, is more readable, and that's the one I go with, but it's totally up to you.

Hope this helps! You always have manual code formatting to fall back on =)